# B-tree recursive search C++

Tags: c++, recursion, b-tree

This function recursively calls itself to search the Btree and returns true if the value is found, and false if it is not found.  I also want it to cout "not found" one time at the end if it is not found.  It works fine except that it says "not found" numerous times (everytime it goes down a level it says not found) since it calls itself.

```
bool lookup(int val, btnode *n) //returns true/false if value is in btree
{

if (n==NULL) return false; //empty tree

for (int i=0;i< n->count;i++) //check in present node for the val
    if(n->value[i]==val)
    {
        flag = true;
        return true;
    }



//check in child node

    for(int i =0;i<n->count;i++) //check for child node
    {   if(val < n->value[i])
        {   cout<<"checking a different node."<<endl;
            lookup(val,n->child[i]);
        }
    }
    if(val > n->value[(n->count)-1])
    {
        cout<<"searching a right subtree"<<endl;
        lookup(val, n->child[n->count]);
    }
if (flag==false)
return false;
else return true;
}

bool lookup2(int val, btnode *n)
{
if(lookup(val, n)==false)
{
    cout<<"not found"<<endl;
    return false;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Found it"<<endl;
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have two functions. One that does the actual printing, and the one that you have right now which does the work recursively.

Comment: Why not just do this at the caller, rather than trying to do it in the method here?

Comment: Also a `bool contains()` function almost never more useful than `location find()`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to make an auxiliary method that calls this lookup function, and does the printing. Something like:

```
bool lookup_print(int val, btnode *n) {
    bool found = lookup(val, n);
    if (found) {
        cout << "Found it!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Not found..." << endl;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Also, you need to make sure that your recursive calls are returning their values if they do find a node. So everywhere you recurse, you'll want something like:

```
bool found = lookup(val,n->child[i]);
if (found) {
    return found;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately I get a false "not found" unless the value is in the root node.  I.e. the function traverses down to the child node, which returns true but then the top function will return false.  Basically, if it return true I want to be done, break out of the recursion cycle, and return true.  Otherwise return false.

Comment: Ok I took your advice and added an auxiliary function called lookup2.  The thing I had to change was to put a static flag that switches to true when it's found.

Comment: @Xymostech answer is correct for the main problem you are complaining about. The second issue is that you don't perform your search correctly. You need to fix that too.

Comment: the second issue is that you don't `return` the recursive `lookup` result.

Comment: and, at the end of the `lookup` function, replace `if (flag == false) ...` by `return false;` because if your execution reaches that point, it means it didn't find anything.